# After installing Xcode, can't get git to work on command line

Tags: xcode, git

I just downloaded Xcode 5.0.1 which I thought comes with git. But when I do a git command on the command line, I get a file not found.

Would anyone know how I can either add and commit through Xcode, or get the git command to work on my command line?

Comment: Did you install the command line tools?

Comment: @trojanfoe I didn't install the command line tools. Which tools should I have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Install the command line tools, which you can do from the command line itself:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Comment: is that meant to be copied in the command line? I went to /Applications/Xcode and did that command and I am getting an error: xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '-install'.

Comment: @Genadinik It's meant to be typed on the command line and notice it's `--install` not `-install`.

Comment: I tried it both ways with the -- and - but both got that same error